# Can there be any problems with accessing Heroku application from Russia?

Tags: heroku

I want to host a production Rails application on Heroku but have some doubts. Can there be any problems with accessing application from Russia because of the Roskomnadzor ban?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku runs on Amazon Web Services, and [it looks like many AWS IP addresses have been blocked in the past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_websites_blocked_in_Russia):

> On 13 April 2018, messaging service Telegram was banned... The ban has been enforced via the blockage of over 15.8 million IP addresses. IPs associated with Amazon Web Services and Google Cloud Platform are included in the block, due to Telegram's use of these platforms; this measure resulted in collateral damage due to usage of the platforms by other services in the country, including... many other unknown websites being blocked for no reason for a month.

I'm not sure that any host would be completely safe from this kind of block.